# How to filter Excel worksheet programmatically without Interop

Tags: c#, excel

I have a protected excel sheet, where i need to filter against the Department and read the users under the department programmatically. I dont have office installed on the execution enviornment.

Please suggest the possible ways of achieving this solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: EPPLus is probably the library I would reach for, what version of Excel?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on whether or not office needs to be installed, but we use Flexcell, it seems to be pretty powerful and versatile tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/). It's free and they have versions to work with both xls and xlsx.